# Why does Bootstrap destroys my normal css layout and how do I fix it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

first of all excuse my language, this is my third language and I'm new.

I'd like to do a little website with html, css and bootstrap that doesn't need to be responsive. 
So I did a sticky Navbar with javascript and css  which looks pretty good. Because I want to use ajax (for not having to write the navbar on each html-file) and Bootstrap (for some buttons, modals etc..)

So I added Bootstrap in my html-doc and now the style of my whole navbar is different. It's not even sticky anymore and has a weird white border at the bottom.

Would be great if you could help me.

I am using Brackets, so all this stuff is local and I am not planning to  make a real website out of it.

Merry Christmas to you all!
Basti

Comment: It's a bit difficult to answer since you didn't provide any code or live demo. However why don't you use the navbar directly from bootstrap? https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navbar/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**WHY?**

Your css declaretions had overrided by bootstrap declaretions:

For example I tried to set `color:red` but look what happend:

[image]

**You have to use this steps to minimize the conflict between your css and bootstrap css:**

- Set your css link below bootstrap links

  `<link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
   <link href="yourCss.css" rel="stylesheet">`
- Use [Specificity](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Specificity) in css as own `id` or `class`

  > Specificity is the means by which browsers decide which CSS property
  >   values are the most relevant to an element and, therefore, will be
  >   applied. Specificity is based on the matching rules which are composed
  >   of different sorts of CSS selectors.
- In case that your css declaretion had overrided use [`!important`](https://css-tricks.com/when-using-important-is-the-right-choice/)

  For eample `color:red!important`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap is the frontend framework it comes with pre defined classes that is the main reason your website style got changed to fix this you can add a custom css so for example one of the pre defined class in bootstrap looks like this

```html
<div class="alert alert-primary" role="alert">
  A simple primary alert—check it out!
</div>
```

Notice that "alert alert-primary" classes (there are 2 classes used first one is alert and second one is alert-primary), This is responsible for the pre defined styles.
So, To fix your issue you can add another class similarly and define its custom style in CSS file as per your need.
So adding another class in the above example will look like this

```html
<div class="alert alert-primary anotherClass" role="alert">
  A simple primary alert—check it out!
</div>
```

and then style this by targeting the same class in CSS like this

```css
.anotherClass {
  /*your styles go here*/
}
```

> Do not forget to link the CSS file.